# How to strip HTML ASCII codes from a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

I have a string that I'm building dynamically while a user is entering data into a textbox, I'm capturing input as it's being entered and saving it to a global variable as follows:

e.g.

```
var uid = '';

function buildString(e) {  
    var keynum = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which; 
    uid += String.fromCharCode(keynum);  
}
```

I notice that the string has HTML ASCII codes appended in front of each character that was typed.

e.g.

> 091[041)062>030RS04800546029GS

so

091 = [

041 = )

062 = >

048 = 0

etc.

I don't want these codes to be present in the string, is there a regex, or some other method in Javascript, that will strip just the codes out without stripping actual, valid, numbers that were entered?

Comment: What's the rest of your code, because normally String.fromCharCode() does not return the ASCII numbers, just the character itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not using the best event for what you're trying to do. Your code should mostly work for the `keypress` event ([example](http://jsbin.com/afoju3)), but won't work well at all for `keyup` or `keydown`.

But just listening for `keypress` won't let you build up a string of what keys were pressed. For instance, using the example above, if I type "abcd" then right-arrow twice then "xx", the built-up string will be "abcdxx" where what's showing in the text box is "abxxcd". So more sophistication will be required.

Here there be dragons. For a good idea of the madness around JavaScript keyboard events, [this site](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) has great information.